# Difference between Team Foundation Server and Team Services

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

What is the difference between Microsoft Team Foundation Server and Microsoft Team Services?

Are Team Services also made for continuous integration and can it be used together with a self hosted git service?

Hope this is not off topic, thank a lot if some one could clearify this!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are basically the same product, except one is cloud-hosted by Microsoft and the other is an on-premise installation.

VSTS gets features first, because it's on a 3-week release cycle. TFS is on the same release/update timeframe as Visual Studio for the most part.

The continuous integration piece allows you to use TFVC, TFS/VSTS-hosted Git, GitHub, Subversion (VSTS only at the moment), or any external Git provider.

Comment: @DanielMann - do you happen to know if the plugins in the Team Services market place (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/#VSTS) also work in Team Foundation Server? Or, is marketplace content exclusive to VSTS?

Comment: @RobDavis Not yet. On-prem TFS doesn't support extensions at present, although extension support is currently slated for TFS 2015 Update 2, per https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso

Comment: @DanielMann - thank you very much. I was hoping to use that PackageManagement extension. Good to know support will be there eventually though!

Comment: Just wanted to update that I'm using TFS 2015 update 2.1 and it supports extension from the visual studio market. And also you may read a bit more on TFS vs. VSTS in here: http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/definition/Visual-Studio-Team-System

Comment: I don't suppose you know if VSTS can publish our web app to our local IIS server (given the credentials)? Many thanks!