# Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

To be clear, I am not asking about about version control, or capabilities of the back end, but the front with the tie in with the interested parties. *(Contributors, Viewers, Users)*

Would those that work with both TFS and VSTS, would you say that TFS and VSTS have all the same "**Visual**" components (comparable version coalition) with the difference of placement being:

- TFS is to SERVER (Designated/Local Server)
- VSTS is to CLOUD (Online servers)

I have read all of the comparable but none talk to this aspect that I can find.

**i.e. do you see the same portal pages and project counter parts in TFS as you do in VSTS?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Team Foundation Server and Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594500/difference-between-team-foundation-server-and-team-services)

Comment: So do you see the same portal on a TFS Share point site as you do the VSTS Project site?

Comment: TFS and VSTS are exactly the same platform. TFS is hosted on-prem. VSTS is hosted by Microsoft in the cloud. TFS as of 2018 does not support Sharepoint at all, and VSTS never has.

Comment: But they have the same Project pages to display to users?

Comment: Yes. It is, for all intents and purposes, the exact same software.

Comment: Wouldn't you say this is not a duplicate question of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594500/difference-between-team-foundation-server-and-team-services"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you first go through the official doc from MSDN: [Understand differences between VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/about-vsts-tfs?view=vsts)

> - VSTS is the **cloud offering** that provides a scalable, reliable, and    globally available hosted service. It is backed by a 99.9% SLA,
>   monitored by our 24-7 operations team, and available in local data
>   centers around the world.
> - Team Foundation Server is **the on-premises offering built on a SQL    Server backend.** Organizations typically choose on-premises TFS when
>   they need their data to stay within your network, or they want access
>   to SharePoint sites and SQL Server reporting services that integrate
>   with TFS data and tools.

### Fundamental differences between TFS and VSTS

- Scope and scale data
- Authentication
- Users and groups
- Manage user access
- Security and data protection

### Key feature differences between VSTS and TFS

- Process customization
- Reporting

You could review the details for the front with the tie in with the interested parties. (Contributors, Viewers, Users)

Back to your question, *do they have the same Project pages to display to users? *  It's basically the same, most new features are released to Visual Studio Team Services first and are integrated into Team Foundation Server with a bit of a delay. Some features are available in VSTS which depend on cloud resources, so they're not likely to move to TFS anytime soon.

Also take a look at this similar question: [Future of TFS vs VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893069/future-of-tfs-vs-vsts)